# error loading archive into app store swift ios

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm trying to upload the archive to app store, but this error crashes

No suitable application records were found. Verify your bundle identifier 'org.cocoapods.GoogleUtilities' is correct.

I have an admob framework connected via pods, but I have no idea what google utilites is

Answer (score -1):

You should keep a unique bundle identifier for your project.
[ [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2bA9.png][1]

com.yourName.projectName.

YourName come automatically from your Apple ID .So First verify your Apple ID.
And project name you should keep unique.It's not similar with other project.
And don't use cocoaPods name in your project name.

GooleUtilities : This service provides utilities for string encoding/decoding, date formatting, JSON manipulation, and other miscellaneous tasks.

Comment: When registering with admob, I specified a bundle ID and in the application it is correct what could be the problem?

Comment: Your project name seem not correct , please restart your project with a specific  name and related to project too.